# Euler's theorem for homogeneous function proof !!

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Here is a link for those who want to take a look at the theorem.

(http://people.hss.caltech.edu/~kcb/Notes/EulerHomogeneity.pdf)

I want to prove: if $f\left(tx\right)=t^{p}f\left(x\right)$, then we get $x \nabla f=pf\left(x\right)$.

I considered a function $g\left(t\right)=f\left(tx\right)$ for fixed $x$ and I took a derivative of $g$ and let $t=1.$

But, I am not sure whether this is a complete proof, since I considered only some fixed vector $\vec{x}$ not all $x$.

So, What should I do?

Comment: But your proof didn't use anything specific about that vector $x$. So, for every other vector you apply the same proof.

Comment: So, is my proof valid..?

Comment: I don't know that. I haven't seen it.